# Indexes in MySQL for order by DESC, BETWEEN and several possible sets of fields for query

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, range, between

I am currently building a dating site, so the main performance bottleneck expected to be from getting users profiles (and much more rarely add new profiles- so we read more often than write).

currently, I have two tables

1) users - (`id, user_name,email,password`)

2) person - (`id, sex, age, sexual_oreintationm, user_registration_date, user_last_activity` and so on - quite a lot of fields)

Both are connected by ID(it's the same number for two tables, and there is the constraint for it)

(I placed `user_registration_date, user_last_activity` fields in person table in order to not use join)

This is the general query for retrieving data (but fields may vary)

```
select * from
(SELECT person.id
FROM person
left join site_users on person.id=site_users.id
where
sex =1
and sexual_orientation =1
and relationship =1
and employment = 1
and smoke = 1
and alcohol =1
and sport = 1
and health = 1
and virus_hiv =1
and virus_hepatitis_c = 1
and (height BETWEEN 110 and 180)
and (weight BETWEEN 50 and 250)
and education > 1
order by site_users.user_registration_date
Limit 50 offset 0) as t
join person on  t.id=person.id
join site_users on t.id = site_users.id;
```

All questions related to compound Indexes

1) Is it possible in **MYSQL** to use several **BETWEEN** conditions while using indexes for it? (in testing I have concluded that - **MSYQL** can use only  the first BETWEEN condition and if it is included in the index in the order that corresponds to order of conditions in **SELECT QUERY**).

2) Does *MYSQL* use indexes for **ORDER BY DESC** (for instance `user_registation_date`)? On what exact position in a compound index do I need put the `user_registation_date` filed to make it work?

3) Do I need to put the ID filed in the compound index? On what exact place?
(I mean in the best case scenario - will it lead to MYSQL not having to read the real table at all, only reading data from Indexes?)

4) How do I create compound indexes for different sets of fields?

e.g. - uses want to filter ( **sex = 1, orientation =2**) or (**height > 180 and weight < 100**) Do I need to create every possible combination of indexes? (It sounds insane)

5) How can I possible further optimize my query? (I need use order by, limit and offset for pagination)

Comment: Try feeding your query into an EXPLAIN statement (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to see exactly how/which indexes are used and identify bottlenecks. There is also a graphical tool in the MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read https://use-the-index-luke.com

> 1) Is it possible in MYSQL to use several BETWEEN conditions while using indexes for it?

The simple answer is no, the query planner can only do a range scan on the first column of a multicolumn index.

The more complex answer is to do something like this

```
SELECT id, whatever
FROM tbl
WHERE col1 BETWEEN val AND val
  AND id IN (SELECT id FROM whatever WHERE col2 BETWEEN x AND y)
```

Each subquery can use a different index. This isn't amazingly efficient, but it is better than a full table scan.

> (... I have concluded that - MySQL can use only the first BETWEEN condition and if it is included in the index in the order that corresponds to order of conditions in SELECT query)

Correct.

> 2) Does MySQL use indexes for ORDER BY DESC

Yes. In MySQL 8 the developers added [descending indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html), which helped `ORDER BY ... DESC` to be more efficient. But it can use the index in any case.
 (for instance user_registation_date)? On what exact position in a compound index do I need put the user_registation_date filed to make it work?

> 3) Do I need to put the ID filed in the compound index?

In InnoDB tables, the pk is implicitly part of each index. So, in InnoDB, no. In MyISAM, yes.

> (... in the best case scenario - will it lead to MYSQL not having to read the real table at all, only reading data from Indexes?)

If you put all columns required to satisfy your query in the index, the query planner does not need to read the real table. That's called a compound covering index.

> 4) How do I create compound indexes for different sets of fields?

If you have many combinations of search criteria and you must use indexes to search for them, you need indexes in appropriate combinations. This can indeed make you think you need a ridiculous number of indexes.  But keep in mind that you can use an index to narrow down the search, then scan fewer rows one by one to do the rest of the filtering. If you index columns having high selectivity, this helps performance, but not perfectly.

Wnat kind of column has high selectivity?  Date of birth potentially does, because there's a wide distribution of values in it. Gender generally does not, because most values have one of two values.

You can always add indexes as you discover you need them. As a database grows in production, generally indexes get  added (and deleted) based on experience.

> e.g. - users want to filter ( sex = 1, orientation =2) or (height > 180 and weight < 100)

`OR` is a special case, because neither side of the `OR` clause can be used to narrow down the search. You may want to use the `WHERE id IN (subquery)` pattern mentioned above for these.

> 5) How can I possible further optimize my query? (I need use order by, limit and offset for pagination)

`SELECT lots of stuff ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT ... OFFSET ...` is a notorious performance antipattern.  Why? the query planner sorts a lot of data then discards most of it. You can try a deferred join. This uses a subquery to retrieve the relevant ids, then join the details.  Something like this:

```
   SELECT whatever, whatever, whatever ...
     FROM table a
    WHERE id IN (
                  SELECT id  
                    FROM table
                   WHERE filter-criterion
                     AND filter-criterion
                   ORDER BY something DESC, anotherthing
                   LIMIT k OFFSET j
                )
    ORDER BY something DESC, anotherthing
```

This allows the query planner to sort many fewer columns with limit and offset, then retrieve all the columns needed for just the required subset of the rows.

> Where in an index should a column be placed to support `ORDER BY thatcolumn`

An index is random-accessed, then sequentially accessed in an efficient query.

For example

```
 SELECT whatever
   FROM table
  WHERE gender='f'
    AND category = 1
    AND dob >= '2001-01-01
    AND dob < '2010-01-01'
  ORDER BY acoount_balance
```

exploits a BTREE (sorted) index on `(category, gender, dob, account_balance)` because it can random access the index to the first eligible entry, then scan it sequentially to the last eligible entry.  As it scans each entry, it picks up the `account_balance` value and uses it to sort.  This is, basically, covering index behavior.

```
 SELECT whatever
   FROM table
  WHERE gender='f'
    AND category = 1
    AND dob >= '2001-01-01
    AND dob < '2010-01-01'
  ORDER BY dob
```

is a special case. Upon finding the first elibile index entry, MySQL exploits the fact that its ORDER BY requirement can be satisfied as it scans the index sequentiallly.

**Pro tip**: Don't overthink this index stuff when building a new application for production use. Until your tables grow large, you won't need intricate indexes. When they do grow large, you'll discover your guesses about the right indexes were at least somewhat wrong. On a growing real-world database it's standard practice to take a look at the slow queries every few weeks, use `EXPLAIN` to figure out how MySQL satisfies them, and add or drop indexes as needed to enhance performance for the cases your users actually care about.

Comment: Can any subquery use a different index?

Like in this example 
SELECT id, whatever
FROM tbl
WHERE col1 BETWEEN val AND val
  AND id IN (SELECT id FROM whatever WHERE col2 BETWEEN x AND y)

I need to create only one index, which contains the only one filed - col2  and the sub subquery can use it separately?

What is better - "id IN" or "Union unique" ?

And where (what position) do I place a field for "order by" in a compound index.?
The very last?
Will it work if the index wasn't used fully (didn't come to the last position)

Answer (score 0):

- (Disagreeing with O. Jones.)  I doubt seriously if the outer part of this example will be able to effectively use two indexes and be any faster.  Once it gets to the outer part, it will need a composite index for `col1` and `id`, but it will not get past the first column since it is a "range".

  `WHERE col1 BETWEEN val AND val
     AND id IN (SELECT id FROM whatever WHERE col2 BETWEEN x AND y)`
- Even before MySQL 8, an index may be used for ORDER BY x DESC -- But it is very unlikely that your complex queries can get past the WHERE to get to the ORDER BY, whether ASC or DESC, whether 8.0 or earlier.
- I recommend tacking on `id` at the end of any indexes *where you expect to use it*.  This is a clue to the reader; it has no impact on the space or performance.
- "Reading entirely from the index" is called "index scan" (if scanning), "Using index" (in `EXPLAIN`), or "covering index" (in theoretical discussions).  It may be faster because it may have the columns in a better order or the index may be smaller.  This latter case is especially handy if the table/index is bigger than can be cached in RAM.
- Start a composite index with field(s) that are tested by `=` (sex, sport, ...), then you get *one* chance to add another column for a range.
- If the `WHERE` is all `=` and you start the index with *exactly* that set of columns (probably not practical in your app), *then* tack on the `ORDER BY` column(s).  Then, the Optimizer *may* avoid sorting for the `ORDER BY` and *may* be able to stop with the `LIMIT`.
- With `WHERE a=1 AND c=2` (no mention of `b`), `INDEX(a,b,c)` won't get past `a`.  Instead `INDEX(a,c,...)` or `INDEX(c,a,...)` will be optimal.
- Since you seem to have a lot of true/false flags, consider using a `SET` or `INT` to hold a bunch of them.  An index won't help (unless covering), but it will significantly shrink the size of the table.
- I discuss more about making indexes here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql
- Only MySQL 8.0 can handle Optimize a mixture of directions:  `ORDER BY x ASC, y DESC`.  (Older version handle it by collecting the possible rows, sorting, then look at `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.)

But let's go back to **the real problem** -- You have a large number of attributes and users can specify any subset of them.  This leads to an impossible-to-optimize situation.  So, what I recommend is to identify a subset of attributes -- the ones most often used -- as columns.  Then throw the rest into a `JSON` string that is *not* looked at by MySQL.  Instead, the app does a second level of filtering.  With the 'common' columns, make a few 2- or 3- column indexes.  (Note my `a,b,c` example above.)

A discussion of EAV:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

Another thought:

`sex` + `orientation` could perhaps be turned into `ENUM('MF', 'FM', 'MM', 'FF', ...)` where `MF` means "Male looking for Female".  And use this column as the first column in most indexes.  (OK, I don't know how to represent "Mail looking for Either" in a practical way.  It may involve a `UNION` of two queries.)